# Is it possible to use` $sum` in the `$match` stage of mongo aggregation and how?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a `gifts` collection in mongodb with four items inside it. how do I query the db so that I get only gifts that the sum of their `amount` is less-than-or-equal-to 5500? 
   so for example from these four gifts in db:

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "amount": 3000,
}, 
{
   "_id": 2,
   "amount": 2000,
},
{
   "_id": 3,
   "amount": 1000,
},
{
   "_id": 4,
   "amount": 5000,
}
```

The query should return the first two only:

```
{
   "_id": 1,
   "amount": 3000,
}, 
{
   "_id": 1,
   "amount": 2000,
},
```

I think I should use mongo **aggregation**? if so, what is the syntax?
I had some googling, I know how to use `$sum` in the `$group` stage, but I don't know how to use it in the `$match` stage. is it event possible to do so?

P.S: I assumend I should use `$sum` in `$match`, Am I supposed to group them first? if so, how do I tell mongo to make a group where the sum of amounts in that group is less-than-or-equal-to 5500?

Thanks for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: How do you group them? In your example.'

Comment: Sorry. I'm using `$group` somewhere else. what I meant was I know how to use `$sum` in the `$group` stage. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

You're going the right way.

First store your `$sum` in a variable then filter them with `$match`:

```
db.gifts.aggregate([
    {$match: {}}, // Initial query
    {$group: {
         _id: '$code', // Assume your gift could be grouped by a unique code
         sum: {$sum: '$amount'}, // Sum all amount per group
         items: {$push: '$$ROOT'} // Push all gift item to an array
    }},
    {$match: {sum: {$lte: 5500}}}, // Filter group where sum <= 5500
    {$unwind: '$items'}, // Unwind items array to get all match field
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$items'}} // Use this stage to get back the original items
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I see the problem is I don't have any unique $code to have as the _id of the group. meaning the gifts has nothing in common and I only have `5500` which I should use the gifts to satisfy. do you have any Idea what can I do? right now, each gift is a group itself cause I gave the _id of the gift as the _id of the group.(which is wrong)

Comment: You should and have to provide a unique code to each gift. Otherwise your document you cannot group them

Comment: ok. Is there any way to get those first two gifts in a query wothout using aggregation? I just want to give the user a discount worth 5500(or less, in this case 3000 + 2000 = 5000) and change the amount of those first two gifts to 0 (meaning they're used.)